# Реклама с хостинга

Tags: html, css, хостинг

Всех приветствую. Это мой первый опыт с установкой лендинга на хостинг. Я установил свой лендинг на хостинг REG.RU, но на сайте стала появляться реклама. Можно ли ее как-то скрыть? Ссылка на сайт kogan-museum.ru

Comment: Хостинг бесплатный?

Comment: @ksa, нет, выбран платный тариф

Comment: Тогда стоит обсудить эту проблему с хостером. Т.к. рекламу обычно пихают принудительно на бесплатных хостингах...

Comment: @ksa, может ли содержаться алгоритм отображения рекламы в какой-нибудь из использованных мной библиотек?

Comment: Замечал такое, что реклама бывает если нет ssl сертификата, попробуйте установите бесплатный от Let's Encrypt

Comment: @АлексейМельников, спасибо большое, помогло!

Comment: Смотря какие библиотеки... Рекламу может "подкинуть" любой участник "сборки" твоей страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Стоял встроенный SSL сертификат, заменил его на новый от Let's Encrypt - проблема решилась